# How to fix HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, dto

I get this error when trying to do HTTP request using DTO.

Simple example of DTO:

```
    private String id;

    @NotBlank
    @EnumConstraint(message = "Invalid type for DTO", enumClazz = TypeEnum.class)
    private String type;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    private String name;
```

Following example works if I use DTO using locally created Java class and just import it.
But I use dependency of another repository with DTOs that has javax.validation.
@EnumConstraint and @Size validations work correctly.
But @NotBlank validation throws unexpected error:

```
HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call
```

I thought it's a problem of @NotBlank annotation, so I've created custom validator with same logic - didn't help. Using another similar annotation @NotEmpty - also didn't fix the problem.
I also tried to follow some topics by adding:

1. `spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.validation.mode=none`
2. adding @Bean to @Configuration - LocalValidatorFactoryBean.
   Nothing helped for me.

How could I fix this problem?